# App Stop Working without error and mixing versions issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I'm clicking on share icon then application stopped and it doesn't show any error in logcat, only five lines which doesn't seems like an error to me. Also, there are 5 fragment, when I open fragment 4 after opening app, it stopped but when I go to fragment 2 then 3 then 5, it doesn't stop. Even my minSdkVersion 15 and targetSdkVersion 18, my app is not running, it's stopped in most devices.

There's a warning shows in gradle (Module:App) on appcompat

```
all com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version found versions 26.1.0, 25.2.0
```

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.+'

    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // ripple effect library
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Activity

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.adapter.AdapterComments;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.connection.API;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.connection.RestAdapter;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.connection.callbacks.CallbackDetailsPost;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.data.AppConfig;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.data.Constant;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.data.SharedPref;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.model.Comment;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.model.Post;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.realm.RealmController;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.utils.NetworkCheck;
import com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit.utils.Tools;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ActivityPostDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
    public static final String EXTRA_NOTIF = "key.EXTRA_NOTIF";

    // give preparation animation activity transition
    public static void navigate(AppCompatActivity activity, View transitionView, Post obj) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ActivityPostDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJC, obj);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, transitionView, EXTRA_OBJC);
        ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle());
    }

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private View parent_view;
    private MenuItem read_later_menu;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipe_refresh;

    // extra obj
    private Post post;
    private boolean from_notif;

    private SharedPref sharedPref;
    private boolean flag_read_later;
    private Call<CallbackDetailsPost> callbackCall = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_details);
        parent_view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        swipe_refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);

        // animation transition
        ViewCompat.setTransitionName(findViewById(R.id.image), EXTRA_OBJC);

        // get extra object
        post = (Post) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_OBJC);
        from_notif = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_NOTIF, false);
        initToolbar();

        displayPostData(true);
        prepareAds();

        if (post.isDraft()) requestAction();

        // on swipe
        swipe_refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                requestAction();
            }
        });

        // get enabled controllers
        Tools.requestInfoApi(this);

        // analytics tracking
        ThisApplication.getInstance().trackScreenView("View post : "+post.title_plain);

    }

    private void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("");
    }

    private void requestDetailsPostApi() {
        API api = RestAdapter.createAPI();
        callbackCall = api.getPostDetialsById(post.id);
        callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackDetailsPost>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CallbackDetailsPost> call, Response<CallbackDetailsPost> response) {
                CallbackDetailsPost resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.status.equals("ok")) {
                    post = resp.post;
                    displayPostData(false);
                    swipeProgress(false);
                } else {
                    onFailRequest();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CallbackDetailsPost> call, Throwable t) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) onFailRequest();
            }

        });
    }

    private void requestAction() {
        showFailedView(false, "");
        swipeProgress(true);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestDetailsPostApi();
            }
        }, Constant.DELAY_TIME_MEDIUM);
    }

    private void onFailRequest() {
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (NetworkCheck.isConnect(this)) {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.failed_text));
        } else {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.no_internet_text));
        }
    }

    private void displayPostData(boolean is_draft) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(Html.fromHtml(post.title));

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.content);
        String html_data = "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> ";
        html_data += post.content;
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings();
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadData(html_data, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
        // disable scroll on touch
        webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }
        });

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.date)).setText(Tools.getFormatedDate(post.date));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment)).setText(post.comment_count + "");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_comment)).setText(getString(R.string.show_tv_comments) + " (" + post.comment_count + ")");
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.category)).setText(Html.fromHtml(Tools.getCategoryTxt(post.categories)));
        Tools.displayImageThumbnail(this, post, ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image)));

        if(is_draft){
           return;
        }
        // when show comments click
        ((MaterialRippleLayout) findViewById(R.id.bt_show_comment)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (post.comments.size() <= 0) {
                    Snackbar.make(parent_view, R.string.post_have_no_comment, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                dialogShowComments(post.comments);
            }
        });

        // when post comments click
        ((MaterialRippleLayout) findViewById(R.id.bt_send_comment)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!AppConfig.MUST_REGISTER_TO_COMMENT) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityPostDetails.this, ActivityWebView.class);
                    if (sharedPref.isRespondEnabled()) {
                        i = new Intent(ActivityPostDetails.this, ActivitySendComment.class);
                    }
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJC, post);
                    startActivity(i);
                } else {
                    Tools.dialogCommentNeedLogin(ActivityPostDetails.this, post.url);
                }
            }
        });
        Snackbar.make(parent_view, R.string.post_detail_displayed_msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int item_id = item.getItemId();
        if (item_id == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        } else if (item_id == R.id.action_share) {
            Tools.methodShare(ActivityPostDetails.this, post);
        } else if (item_id == R.id.action_later) {
            if (post.isDraft()) {
                Snackbar.make(parent_view, R.string.cannot_add_to_read_later, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            String str;
            if (flag_read_later) {
                RealmController.with(this).deletePost(post.id);
                str = getString(R.string.remove_from_msg);
            } else {
                RealmController.with(this).savePost(post);
                str = getString(R.string.added_to_msg);
            }
            Snackbar.make(parent_view, "Post " + str + " Read Later", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            refreshReadLaterMenu();
        } else if (item_id == R.id.action_browser) {
            Tools.directLinkToBrowser(this, post.url);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity_post_details, menu);
        read_later_menu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_later);
        refreshReadLaterMenu();
        return true;
    }

    private void dialogShowComments(List<Comment> items) {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityPostDetails.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // before
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_comments);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        AdapterComments mAdapter = new AdapterComments(this, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        ((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img_close)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    }

    private void refreshReadLaterMenu() {
        flag_read_later = RealmController.with(this).getPost(post.id) != null;
        Drawable drawable = read_later_menu.getIcon();
        if (flag_read_later) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        } else {
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }

    private void prepareAds() {
        if (AppConfig.ENABLE_ADSENSE && NetworkCheck.isConnect(getApplicationContext())) {
            AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_layout)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void showFailedView(boolean show, String message) {
        View lyt_failed = (View) findViewById(R.id.lyt_failed);
        View lyt_main_content = (View) findViewById(R.id.lyt_main_content);

        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.failed_message)).setText(message);
        if (show) {
            lyt_main_content.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            lyt_main_content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.failed_retry)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestAction();
            }
        });
    }

    private void swipeProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (!show) {
            swipe_refresh.setRefreshing(show);
            return;
        }
        swipe_refresh.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipe_refresh.setRefreshing(show);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(from_notif) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMain.class));
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
12-09 13:56:43.962 6867-6914/com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ActivityPostDetails, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8020478545849927104, timestamp=1512808003957, fatal=1}]
12-09 13:56:43.979 6867-6914/com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-09 13:56:43.985 6867-6914/com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 23008
12-09 13:56:43.991 6867-6914/com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=23008, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ActivityPostDetails, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8020478545849927104}]
12-09 13:56:44.012 6867-6914/com.balrajarpit.balrajarpit V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
```

Comment: One of your library imported recently has a support 25! What is the last added library???

Comment: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

Comment: Oooooh we can not remove that check the error lines some of your previous were made with 25 may be retrofit and update to the one with 26. Otherwise whenever you see 26 put 25 instead. Although this will send you back!

Comment: Updated retrofit with latest but facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the problem in this case, but using different versions of support libraries can cause runtime crashes. You can find the ones that use a different version (maybe used internally by another library) by executing the following command in (android studio) terminal:

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

If the command doesn't work, you maybe have to configure a gradle wrapper first. To do so, add the following to your project build.gradle file:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1'
}
```

and execute the command

```
gradle wrapper
```

from terminal. If it still doesn't work, gradle might not be in your PATH, you can find it in the Android Studio installation folder if you want to add it.

Once you know which one uses a different version, just add it as a dependency yourself with the correct version to override the other version and sync.

It worked for me this way when I had the problem, hope it helps!

Comment: Executed the command and updated version of realm and every single library with their latest version but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Finally resolved. It was problem with image loading. Due to size of the image, sometime fragment was crashing.